# How i can retrive the data from datagridview row click to corresponding data to another form

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to retrieve data from one form to another form , on gridview click event. I have small code I got it from google search but its giving me error. in this code I was trying to retrieve it to second form datagrid. please check my code. where I am wrong.

```
Private Sub ReceiveGoods_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For j As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.RowCount - 1
            If frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value = True Then
                Dim count As Integer = 0
                For i As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.ColumnCount - 1
                    Me.dgvReceiveGoods.Rows(count).Cells(i).Value = frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
                Next
                count += count
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I am getting this error, while I run.

```
Conversion from string "PO003" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

please help me

[image: Error]

what I have the code that totally wrong code I guess. because what I am trying to do is , I have one gridview, and some data on that, when I click the row on datagrid , I want to open the corresponding information to second form gridview. this is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding...

Me.dgvReceiveGoods.Rows(count).Cells(i).Value = frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value.ToString

Comment: error in this line "If frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value = True Then"

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh okay i get it remove the if statement to transfer all your data into the form:

Private Sub ReceiveGoods_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    For j As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.RowCount - 1
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            For i As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.ColumnCount - 1
                Me.dgvReceiveGoods.Rows(count).Cells(i).Value = frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
            Next
            count += count
       Next
End Sub
```

Or replace the if condition if you want to get all data without NULL value or Nothing

Private Sub ReceiveGoods_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    For j As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.RowCount - 1
        If frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value.ToString <> "" Then
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            For i As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.ColumnCount - 1
                Me.dgvReceiveGoods.Rows(count).Cells(i).Value = frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
            Next
            count += count
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index on this line  Me.dgvReceiveGoods.Rows(count).Cells(i).Value = frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value

Comment: what I have the code that totally wrong code I guess. because what I am trying to do is , I have one gridview, and some data on that, when I click the row on datagrid , I want to open the corresponding information to second form gridview. this is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check if both DataGridView Has The Same Column if not the error may Occur ex. if your passing 10 datas vs 20 datas on other datagridview, the first datagridview will be insufficient to give required data needed by the second datagridview.

Try to analyze this one...

Solution1: DataGridView1 > DataGridview 2

Use this Code

Private Sub ReceiveGoods_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
For j As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.RowCount - 1
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.ColumnCount - 1
            Me.dgvReceiveGoods.Rows(count).Cells(i).Value = frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
        Next
        count += count
   Next
```

End Sub

Solution2:DataGridview1 < DataGridview2

Use this Code

Private Sub ReceiveGoods_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
For j As Integer = 0 To Me.dgvReceiveGoods.RowCount -1
    If frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value.ToString <> "" Then
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.ColumnCount - 1
            Me.dgvReceiveGoods.Rows(count).Cells(i).Value = frmGoodsReceive.dgvPODetails.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
        Next
        count += count
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Solution3:DataGridView1 = DataGridView 2

you can use Both...

Comment: you are right , I have more data than the first gridview, so I tried your second solution , its running no error, but nothing showing on the second gridview(second form).